# Intent.getData() returns the same uri

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-launcher

I am trying to open my app through a url which has a query parameter in it that I need to check to proceed to the next screen. Here is what the Android Manifest for that activity looks like:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ContainerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="myapp" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The app launches fine with the uri https://myapp?groupCode=1234 but the problem is that I am getting the same uri every time (on certain devices) even after I uninstall the app and install it for the first time. Here is where I get the uri

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
Log.d(TAG, "the uri is "+uri);
```

The uri is always

> https://myapp?groupCode=1234

Really lost on this one. I can only reproduce the issue on a couple of devices a samsung s6 is the one I'm working with now. I've tried little things like

```
 android:allowBackup="false"
 android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

I've also tried to capture the new intent in onNewIntent() but I can't seem to get that to fire for this activity. Idea here was to see if setting the new intent would work, but its just mind blowing to me that this doesn't work after a complete uninstall, reinstall and then opening of the app through a url like https://myapp?groupCode=abcd and still getting back the url https://myapp?groupCode=1234

Please help!

EDIT:
I should add that the device I'm not getting it to work on has been using Hockey to get apks onto the device. The way hockey works is kinda crappy, you basically download the apk and then manually install it on the phone. This phone probably has 100 apks on it by now. Is there any way that there is data being cached somewhere where a new app would capture it? I cannot recreate the issue for devices that have not been using hockey/have a ton of apk files. I don't see why this would matter exactly but I'm basically just trying anything at this point.

I will also add that the onNewIntent() was simply not being called because the activity is destroyed by the time you click on the link.